# ASP.NET User Control with attribute priority behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, attributes

**FOUND THE ANSWER MYSELF, see below...**

I'd like to have a very simple user control...

```
<mw:Translate LocalizedText="Some text" />
```

This results in "Some text" in output.

However, if I put it like this:

```
<mw:Translate ID="translate1" LocalizedText="Some text" />Some other text</mw:Translate>
<mw:Translate ID="translate2"/>Some other text</mw:Translate>
```

ID=translate1 results in "Some text" while ID=translate2 renders "Some other text"

Simply, if the LocalizedText attribute is not set, then the text inside the translate tag is rendered. If neither LocalizedText, nor a text inside the element are set, empty string is rendered.

For clarification, LocalizedText attribute is prefered. So if the mw:Translate tag body and the LocalizedText are set, Localized Text is rendered.

I'm writting this just because I'm not sure how to set correctly the UserControl property attributes...

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
namespace MagicWare.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [ParseChildren(true, "InsideText")]
    public class Translate : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
    {
        public string LocalizedText
        {
            get { return Text; }
            set { this.Text = Translations.Translate(Value); }
        }

        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
        public string InsideText { get; set; }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {
                writer.Write(Text);
                return;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InsideText))
            {
                writer.Write(InsideText);
                return;
            }
            writer.Write("");
        }
    }
}
```

**ANSWER**

Everything i needed to know was the existence of the interface **ITextControl**. With it, I just implement a "Text" attribute, which contains the text put inside the tags so it works like the literal control.

Comment: How do you want it to render when you have both?

Comment: LocalizedText attribute is prefered. So if the mw:Translate tag body and the LocalizedText are set, Localized Text is rendered.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything i needed to know was the existence of the interface ITextControl. With it, I just implement a "Text" attribute, which contains the text put inside the tags so it works like the literal control.